# split signup custom policy with sendgrid email

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I used this for integration with sendgrid
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol/policy/SendGrid/DisplayControl_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml
and here is my TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS.xml I get two verification emails with the same code, and I get 'Code has already been verified. Please request a new code.' when click on verify button

```
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <!-- Read only email address to present to the user-->
      <ClaimType Id="readonlyEmail">
        <DisplayName>E-mail Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="isForgotPassword">
        <DisplayName>isForgotPassword</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Whether the user has selected Forgot your Password</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="oldPassword">
        <DisplayName>Old Password</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Enter your old password</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>Password</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopySignInNameToReadOnly" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccount.emailVerification">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.8</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.localaccount.emailVerification.en" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
      <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
      </SupportedLanguages>
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccount.emailVerification.en">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Continue</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </LocalizedResources>
    </Localization>
    <DisplayControls>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id"></Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience"></Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Email Verification</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Email verification only-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
          <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.emailVerification</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
            <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
          <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" /> -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Sign-up self-asserted technical profile without Email verification-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
            <!-- Remove sign-up email verification -->
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Set input the ReadOnlyEmail claim type to prefilled the email address-->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <!-- Sample: Display the ReadOnlyEmail claim type (instead of email claim type)-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <!-- Sample: Disable session management for sign-up page -->
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ForgotPassword">
          <DisplayName>Forgot your password?</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isForgotPassword" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive-PasswordChange">
          <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oldPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account Password Change</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId">
          <DisplayName>Change password (username)</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oldPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive-PasswordChange" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Validate Email on Sign In</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-AAD">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
          </PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopySignInNameToReadOnly" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn">
          <DisplayName>EmailVerifyOnSignIn</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <!-- <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" /> -->
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_EmailVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_WithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step forces email verification on sign in only. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>newUser</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>

    <UserJourney Id="SignUp">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_EmailVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_WithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>

  </UserJourneys>
```